# How can I create docker-compose vhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache2

I use the following stack: https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp

I created the .conf file in the vhosts folder, added to the .yml:

```
extra_hosts: 
  - "laravel.local:127.0.0.1"
```

If I ssh into the webserver I see the conf in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, I see laravel.local in /etc/hosts, but laravel.local doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: doc says "Make sure you add an entry to your system's hosts file for each virtual host." so you need to add an alias on your workstation hosts too. by defaut only 127.0.0.1 is known out of apache container

Comment: Yes, I have to add it on the host OS, no idea why I wanted it in the container, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have to add it on the host OS, no idea why I wanted it in the container